# Decrypt random data (to password)

Tags: javascript, php, security, encryption, passwords

Imagine a web based password manager. It uses in-browser javascript and a symmetric encryption algorithm, encrypted password from server and master password from user to get the site-specific password.

Server should know nothing about master password nor the site-specific password, only the encrypted form. If user uses incorrect master password, then he/she gets incorrect site-specific password, vertifycations should not be possible.

**The problem:**
As javascript does not have good randomness, password generation should be done on the server side. As server must not know the site-specific password, I thought that it could be possible to generate random encrypted form of the site-specific password, and if client decodes it with his/hers master password, only then would the site-specific password come into existance.

Is there a algorithm that would decrypt a decent password from any random-data/master-password combination?
Any ideas on how to implement such thing?

Answer (score 0):

"Plain" symmetric decryption of the random data block will produce another data block with seemingly random data. So yes, you basically let the server provide you some random sequence which you then transform to another random sequence.

Such scheme is not safe from various attacks on the client-side javascript on the client side, though.

Comment: an example of attacs? because if the browser itself is compromised then any browser-based password manager is doomed to fail anyhow?

Comment: @a966821 please check the article on http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: considered, not applicable - https is used anyway, randomness not needed, transferring passwords in plaintext over https does not provide additional security. 
What exactly do you mean by "plain symmetric decryption"?

Comment: @a966821 take a 16-byte block, decrypt it in ECB mode using a 16-byte key (no padding etc. involved).